# Snowflake won't allow an analytic function to be renamed

Tags: query, table, snowflake

In the code below, I can do the LAG and PARTITION BY with no problem as a query.  But I need it as a table. If I do CTAS, I need an alias on the column.  But when I try to put an alias on it, it fails. I think this is valid SQL. But I'm using [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/), so I'm asking it on Super User as I fear this is a vendor issue.

How can I create a table with the output of that query?

```
drop table a;

create table a (
    a1 varchar,
    a2 varchar
);

insert into a values ( 'a', 1 );
insert into a values ( 'a', 3 );
insert into a values ( 'a', 5 );
insert into a values ( 'a', 9 );
insert into a values ( 'b', 1 );
insert into a values ( 'b', 3 );
insert into a values ( 'b', 4 );
insert into a values ( 'c', 3 );
insert into a values ( 'c', 4 );
insert into a values ( 'c', 5 );

-- This works fine.
select a1
     , a2
     , lag(a2)
  over (partition by a1 order by a2)
  from a
;

-- This fails.
select a1
     , a2
     , lag(a2) new_col_name
  over (partition by a1 order by a2)
  from a
;

-- But if I can't name the column, I can't CTAS.
create table b as
select a1
     , a2
     , lag(a2)
  over (partition by a1 order by a2)
  from a
;
```

Output is:

```
status
A successfully dropped.
status
Table A successfully created.
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
number of rows inserted
                      1
A1  A2  LiteralRedacted0
b   1   NULL
b   3   1
b   4   3
c   3   NULL
c   4   3
c   5   4
a   1   NULL
a   3   1
a   5   3
a   9   5
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 4 at position 2 unexpected 'over'.
002022 (42601): SQL compilation error:
Missing column specification
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lag(...) over(...)` is an entire expression, you cannot split it at will. The correct syntax is

```
select a1
     , a2
     , lag(a2) over (partition by a1 order by a2) new_col_name
from a
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL server has another syntax for creating tables from another select.

Also you need to do that all columns named

```
--drop table a;

create table a (
    a1 varchar,
    a2 varchar
);

insert into a values ( 'a', 1 );
insert into a values ( 'a', 3 );
insert into a values ( 'a', 5 );
insert into a values ( 'a', 9 );
insert into a values ( 'b', 1 );
insert into a values ( 'b', 3 );
insert into a values ( 'b', 4 );
insert into a values ( 'c', 3 );
insert into a values ( 'c', 4 );
insert into a values ( 'c', 5 );

-- This works fine.
select a1
     , a2
     , lag(a2)
  over (partition by a1 order by a2)
  from a
;

-- This fails.
select a1
     , a2
     , lag(a2) 
  over (partition by a1 order by a2) as new_col_name
  from a
;

-- But if I can't name the column, I can't CTAS.

select a1
     , a2
     , lag(a2)
  over (partition by a1 order by a2) as new_column

  INTO b
  from a
;
```

| a1 | a2 | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | *null* |
| a | 3 | 1 |
| a | 5 | 3 |
| a | 9 | 5 |
| b | 1 | *null* |
| b | 3 | 1 |
| b | 4 | 3 |
| c | 3 | *null* |
| c | 4 | 3 |
| c | 5 | 4 |

| a1 | a2 | new_col_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | *null* |
| a | 3 | 1 |
| a | 5 | 3 |
| a | 9 | 5 |
| b | 1 | *null* |
| b | 3 | 1 |
| b | 4 | 3 |
| c | 3 | *null* |
| c | 4 | 3 |
| c | 5 | 4 |

```
SELECT * FROM b
```

| a1 | a2 | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | *null* |
| a | 3 | 1 |
| a | 5 | 3 |
| a | 9 | 5 |
| b | 1 | *null* |
| b | 3 | 1 |
| b | 4 | 3 |
| c | 3 | *null* |
| c | 4 | 3 |
| c | 5 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0fvDocMV)

Comment: Oh, flippin' brilliant!  The "lag" and "over" go together.  Duh.  Thank you!!!  I was thinking the lag function stood alone similar to aggregate functions like "min" or "max", so I put the alias right after the function.  But the whole "lag" clause goes to the parenthesis after internal order by clause.  Not just a SQL Server thing.  It works on Snowflake.  Thanks!